# Click on a specific part of HTML element

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a `checkbox element` on my web-page which has a partial link which reads as `Read the conduct risk manual` where in `conduct risk manual` is a link which when clicked on navigates to page that has conduct risk manual listed down.

The HTML structure for this element is as below:

```
 <div class="checkbox">
   <label>
     <input ng-disabled="readonly" type="checkbox" name="policyRead" required="" ng-model="confirmOa.confirmation.policyRead" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-invalid ng-invalid-required xh-highlight">
       <span>Read the <a target="_blank" href="http://somesite.xyz/Conduct%Risk%Manual.pdf">Conduct Risk Manual</a></span>
   </label>
 </div>
```

Now I want to click on a `check-box` which used to work if I click on span element but now even if I try with below combinations of web-driver is still clicking on link `Conduct Risk Manual`

```
1) .//div/label/input[@name='policyRead']
2) .//input[@name='policyRead' and @type='checkbox']
3) .//span[contains(text(),'Read the')]
4) .//span[contains(text(),'Read')]
5) .//input[@name='startDateConfirmed']//preceding::span[1]
```

In the `5th xpath` I have tried clicking on span element using the following HTML element which is correctly identified and clicked.

I have tried many combinations apart from those mentioned above and all the xpath's correctly highlight the expected element which means it is correctly identified. But still web-driver clicks on `Conduct Risk Manual` link and navigates to a new page instead of clicking corresponding checkbox.

Can we make web-driver click on a specific part of an element?

Please check xpath's wherein I have already tried using only 'Read' or 'Read the' portion of span element.

Comment: Which language/ framework you are using?

Comment: @peterpawar I am using Java with TestNG

Comment: can you try with: `.//span[contains(text(),'Read the')]//preceding-sibling::input `

Comment: @peterpawar Still clicked on link with this as well.

Comment: Can you show us the source page? It will be better to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below code.

**Explanation:** Use `text` method with `span` tag, then move ahead with `preceding-sibling` keyword to find `input` tag for clicking the checkbox element.

**Note:** `span` tag use here for reference to get the check-box element text.

```
WebElement checkbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Read the')]//preceding-sibling::input[@name='policyRead']"));
if(!checkbox.isSelected())               // if checkbox is not selected, then only if is condition will execute.
{
  checkbox.click();
}
```

OR

Using `Java-script executor` to click the `checkbox` web-element.

```
WebElement checkbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Read the')]//preceding-sibling::input[@name='policyRead']"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", checkbox);
```

Comment: I have try this code on my end and it's getting click on `check-box` element in both the browsers. I have test this code in `firefox` and `chrome` browser.

Comment: No Jainish I didn't get any error and I had copy pasted the code given by you.

Comment: Will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: Yes it worked for me using java-script executor as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code also as `a` tag is coming over to the checkbox.

```
WebElement checkBox= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Read the')]//preceding-sibling::input[@type='checkbox']"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(checkBox).click().build().perform();`
```

Also add `import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;` .

Comment: can you explain, why you are using `Action class` over here, for clicking the `check-box` web-element.

Comment: @Peter I had already tried using actions and it worked using simple xpath as .//div/label/input[@name='policyRead']

Comment: As mentioned by Jainish.. again I am wondering here that why we need to use actions for getting through this.

Comment: Is it working as your expectations using actions or not?

Comment: `WebElement checkManual = Superclass.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/label/input[@name='policyRead']"));
   Actions act = new Actions(Superclass.driver);
   act.click(checkManual).perform();`

Comment: This worked for me. Didn't had to use moveToElement either. That again brings me to the question why did we need to use actions class for this?